# issue with calendar_date_select gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my error, my usage was based on this link (form builder tab): http://electronicholas.com/calendar

```
ArgumentError in Sales#new

Showing app/views/sales/new.html.erb where line #14 raised:

wrong number of arguments (5 for 4)

Extracted source (around line #14):

11:   <%= f.text_area :description %><br />
12:   <br />
13:   <%= f.label :startdate %>:
14:   <%= f.calendar_date_select :startdate, :embedded => true %><br />
15:   
16: 
17:   <br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of CalendarDateSelect are you using? I have version 1.15. I found something similar in the [bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/calendardateselect/issues/detail?id=127&can=1&q=embedded). Maybe you have an old version and if you update it will be fixed?

I have tried in my app using CalendarDateSelect in a form builder with embedding and it works.

```
<% form_for @project do |form| -%>
  <%= form.calendar_date_select :starts_on, :embedded => true  %>
<% end -%>
```

I get this on the page

```
<input id="project_starts_on" name="project[starts_on]" type="hidden" />
<span id="cds_placeholder_11065" style="display: none; position: absolute;"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
    new CalendarDateSelect( $('cds_placeholder_11065').previous(), {embedded:true, year_range:10} ); 
  //]]>
</script>
```

Make sure you put the includes at the top of your page/layout

```
<%= calendar_date_select_includes -%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you should have used `calendar_date_select_tag` there, instead of `calendar_date_select`.

Comment: I tried other methods but then it wont pass it to the correct input. I want to use the form builder option they say it has...